# look for specific sql requests in java project using regex

Tags: sql, regex, eclipse

What is the best regex to use in order to search all queries in my project with following pattern :

```
select count(*) as count  from ( select  .... )A
```

that is, all queries with one nested sql request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match a multi line select statement

```
select((.|\n)*)from((\n|\s)*)\(((\n|\s)*)select((.|\n)*)\)\w
```

1. select
2. any characters including new lines
3. from
4. spaces and new lines
5. opening parenthesis spaces and new lines
6. select
7. any characters including new lines
8. closing parenthesis
9. a word

Comment: how can I modify the regex so to add the opening parethesis in the middle of it, so that for example select...from...minus...select don't get returned in the results ?

Comment: just by adding `\(` `\)` where you want

Comment: @mounaim Parenthesis added and statement should end with a word

Comment: but one remark is that this regex won't work on multi-line sql requests, how can I overcome this ?

Comment: Exactly what I've just done ;) Thanks a lot man I'll accept your answer :)